# Best Plugins for Blender for importing stuff to Roblox?

Tags: plugins, blender, roblox

Which plugins are the best for Blender and Roblox?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing stuff = meshes?

To export a "mesh" from Blender, select what you would like to export and hit File -> Export -> OBJ. Insert a Mesh part in Roblox Studio. In the properties, hit the little folder icon and select your mesh. Bare in mind meshes have to be under 10k triangles.

To export JUST selection in Blender: https://help.sansar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002888226-3D-model-export-and-setup-tips-using-popular-3D-tools-